# Sum of array values where key is lower than - with fashion

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I need to calculate the sum of the  values in array where key index is lower than... something.

I have done that, by this:

```
$temp_sum = 0;
for($temp_start = 0; $temp_start < 10; $temp_start++)
{
   $temp_sum += $array[$temp_start];
}
```

But my question is... Another way to do this in more fashion way?

With usage of array functions? Maybe one specific array function for this task?

This for loop (or using even foreach loop) doesn't look nice and proper - but maybe it's only way to use standard looping.

Comment: To the users voting to close this question because they deem it "too broad": I don't understand why this question is being marked as "too broad". Can you elaborate? Looks like a concise enough question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loops allow multiple statements inside its expressions, separated by commas. So, you could instantiate `$temp_sum` inside the `for` construct, to make it a little more concise:

```
for($temp_sum = 0, $temp_start = 0; $temp_start < 10; $temp_start++)
{
   $temp_sum += $array[$temp_start];
}
```

I don't know if it necessarily helps readability though. Also, you might want to make sure there's at least 10 elements in `$array` to begin with, if you are not already verifying this.

Another alternative could be:

```
$sum = array_sum( array_slice( $array, 0, 10 ) );
```

but this requires the array keys to start at 0 and be adjacent and sequentially sorted. In other words, this array:

```
$array = [
  13 => 12,
  31 => 23,
  1 => 24,
  0 => 21
  /* ... */
];
```

will create an undesirable result.

Not sure if it's more efficient either, but it's a nice one-liner and it has the possibly added benefit that it won't complain if there's less than 10 elements inside the array. You'll have to decide if that is desirable or not.

---

All in all, I think your initial use of the `for` loop is a pretty good example of a typical use-case. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops, for example, are typically used in cases where you want to iterate *all* elements, not just a limited set.

Comment: Perfect answer, Thank you :)

Comment: amazed by quality of this answer, really appreciated

Comment: @KrystianPolska That's really nice to hear Krystian; thank you! I'm glad you found it helpful.